# How could the relative zero gravity of the International Space Station be canceled?

Tags: gravity, space, nasa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will a machine or a technique ever be possible that allows gravity in space?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6997/will-a-machine-or-a-technique-ever-be-possible-that-allows-gravity-in-space)

I'm wondering how it would be possible for science to cancel out the experience of zero gravity on the International Space Station. i.e., so that astronauts wouldn't float.

Is there some theoretical answer to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

According to Einstein, you can't feel difference between Gravity and Inertial Force. So, to mimic gravity, you can push astronauts at ISS in a non-inertial reference frame. You can do it by accelerating ISS. The only solution while keeping ISS in orbit, is uniform rotation which would cause velocity of astronauts to change direction to feel effects of acceleration.

Practically, matching Earth's gravity feel isn't a joke, by the way. It requires very-very big ISS and very high angular speed. But yes, you can see it in Sci-Fi canons.