# Motion in a vacuum

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, conservation-laws, inertial-frames

If an object is moving through a vacuum, can changes in the object affect this motion?  If the object is spinning could the spin be altered if the object's shape is changed?  Would this object change velocity as an ice skaters velocity changes when they pull in their arms & legs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does a ballerina speed up when she pulls in her arms?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3611/)

Comment: Please note that this site is not a place to obtain solutions to worked problems. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/25301) and [this Meta post for "check my work problems"](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/25301).

Answer (score 1):

The conservation of total momentum dictates that, when there are no external forces, the center of mass of the object moves with constant velocity even when the object changes shape. The conservation of angular momentum dictates that the angular velocity changes when the object's moment of inertia changes due to the change in shape just like in the case of the ice skater.