# Why do cosmic bodies revolve?

Tags: astrophysics, angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, quantum-spin, conservation-laws

Why do cosmic bodies such as planets, stars, satellites revolve?
What made them to revolve after the formation of universe?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/24888/11062, http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12140/11062 and the links therein...

Comment: @Crazy Buddy: Those questions look like duplicates of each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is: angular momentum conservation. Angular momentum equates to the product of [moment of inertia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia) times angular (rotational) velocity. When a gas or dust cloud contracts under the influence of gravity and forms a more compact cosmic body, any nonzero total angular velocity will increase due to the moment of inertia decreasing.