# Why are almost every planet or star rotating?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, conservation-laws, celestial-mechanics

Is there any simple reason? Why is spinning so common?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12140/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/24888/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Of all possible angular momenta a planet/star/system etc could have, having exactly 0 seems fairly unlikely to me