# Why are the orbits of the planets in our solar system along the same basic plane?

Tags: astronomy, astrophysics, planets, solar-system

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are our planets in the solar system all on the same disc/plane/layer?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/26083/why-are-our-planets-in-the-solar-system-all-on-the-same-disc-plane-layer)

After [watching this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=Qwi5L8jcXpg) I realized that the orbits of the planets in our solar system basically reside along a similar 'flat' plane:

[image]

Meaning that the angles of orbit are no greater than 20 degrees (if you still count Pluto as a planetary object).  Why are there none of the planets at a 45 or even 90 degree orbit (in relation to the earth)?  Is this due specifically to the gravitational pull from the Sun?

Answer (score 2):

The shortest answer is that systems "like" to be in low energy states. If we conserve the total angular momentum of the planets, then a flat disc  has the least total kinetic energy.

Consider if a a new planet enters the solar system at a 90 degree angle to the others. The solar system will continue to dissapate energy in collisions and gravitational effects until all planets are roughly in line. This obviously takes a while, but out solar system has had 6? billion to do so.

You might also observe that galaxies are flat discs, while one could imagine stars clumping into a sphere instead. This occurs for the same reason. A flat disc has less kintetic energy than a sphere of stars orbiting in random planes.

Just like how a ball always rolls down a hill, solar systems and galaxies move towards the lowest energy state.

Comment: You've got a lot of the right bits in here, but a mature systems, like ours is so nearly empty that high inclination orbits would mostly be expected to be stable