# If I start spinning a raw egg slowly why does its angular velocity increase spontaneously?

Tags: angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, conservation-laws, home-experiment

If I start spinning a raw egg very slowly in place, why does its angular velocity increase spontaneously? This is something I noticed the other day while cooking. It doesn't do the same thing with a hard-boiled egg, so I assume it has to do something with how the contents of the raw egg are distributed during the spinning process, but I was wondering if someone could fill in the details.

Comment: Relared: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/150795/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/119394/2451 and links therein.

Comment: This only works if you spin it up & then briefly stop the shell, which doesn't stop the fluid contents from rotating.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I was able to do it as he described, though the effect was rather more subtle than the way you describe it.

Comment: Related : Will a boiled egg or a raw egg stop rolling first?: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19260

Answer (score 2):

Never seen that before, so I just tried it. Cool.

I believe that the membrane between the yolk and the white is elastic, so when you first, gently, give the egg a little angular momentum, you are only spinning the white. As the yolk catches up the effective moment of inertia drops, and conservation of momentum therefor implies a higher angular velocity.

Comment: This appears to be reasonable for a short impulse, but for an application of force over a second would mean that the yolk doesn't rotate for most of that time.

Comment: @LDC3 Well, yes. And I only tested it with about a one radian twist given in about half a second. You need a pretty smooth surface to observe the effect under those condiction.