# Why are the planets rotating on their own axis?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, conservation-laws, planets

Earth is revolving around sun because of gravity but what causes the earth to rotate itself?

This question has been already asked [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/142014/), but the answers are like, earth had a collision and it formed moon so it started rotating. But what is it with the case of all other planets?

Every planet is rotating on its own axis that too venus and mercury has no moons, so what caused them rotating?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does the Earth rotate on its axis?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/142014/)

Comment: Another (more general) possible duplicate: [Why does everything spin?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12140/).

Comment: Check also this (non-moon-related) answer: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/142102/75633

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/23104/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Maybe that's an answer to your question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/352836/75633

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you must know how the Earth formed. When the Sun first formed by the compression of nebulae matter, the rest of the nebula consisted of quite a few debris, that began to orbit around the sun. These debris eventually clumped together and formed planets. So basically, the particles that make up the Earth were already in motion. As they clumped together, they still retained their velocity, and of course, their angular momentum about the Earth's to be axis. The Earth has been spinning from the day (can I use the word day?) it was created.

### Further reading (for the fun of it):

1. [Why does the Earth rotate?](https://www.universetoday.com/14491/why-does-the-earth-rotate/)
2. [How was the Sun formed?](https://amp.space.com/19321-sun-formation.html)
3. [Angular momentum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_momentum)