# Do all "normal" black holes rotate?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, angular-momentum, conservation-laws

Can we assume that most (if not all)  black holes are rotating, due to conservation of momentum?

I am excluding the micro world from this question, just thinking of the range of stars on the main sequence of the H-R diagram as they shrink over time.

Can anyone give me an example of non-rotating macro sized B.H., e.g a binary system where each star counter-rotates relative to the other and explain how they may, (if they can)  at least slow down each others's rotational velocity?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12140/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we expect all astrophysical black holes to have nonzero rotation.  If nothing else, a rotating black hole that absorbs even a single particle with net angular momentum will then have nonzero angular momentum.

Comment: That's a very good reference that @Qmechanic gave me (and am I kicking myself ...yes). But then two quick implications: Solving the Schwardschild solution is purely a teaching aid rather than reality and to sum up can we (crudely, I know) ultimately  derive macro spin from scaled up inherent particle spin?

Comment: @irishphysics: well, I wouldn't say that Schwarzschild is useless.  It's TREMENDOUSLY less complicated than Kerr, and the kerr corrections fall off a factor of $r$ faster than the schwarzschild terms, so for many cases, schwarzschild is perfectly good.  Not to mention all o fhte birchoff-style reuslts you can get.

Comment: but yes, I wouldn't conclude too much from kruskal topology.