# Can a black hole be a not spinning one?

Tags: black-holes, angular-momentum

So. There are spinning black holes. Could there be a not spinning black hole?

Or even if it would exist, it would start spinning because of stuff?

Comment: Duplicate e.g. of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/174940/

Answer (score -1):

yes there are black holes which do not spin at all,To know the spin of black holes we need to look for the angular momentum of the FALLING PARTICLES(into the black hole) because if a black hole spins it forces the falling particles to have the same spin(as a consequence of general relativity),so some black holes don't have spin as the falling particles do not spiral instead they just directly fall into it.Falling particles can't produce spin in black holes however they increase its mass a little

Comment: Welcome on Physics SE and thanks for your answer :) it might benefit from quoting sources - also I am unsure how we know that some particles falling into a black hole do not spiral.